# adb install Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Tags: android, visual-studio, ant, adb

Build native .so's and made apk with ant build, wanted to test so did an adb install on an emulator and got the following error:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

I do not get it, an ant zip task to inject /libs/arm64-v8a was done on the apk and unzipping it shows they are there....

I have seen this question and everyone shows gradle solutions, I do not want to use gradle, i want an ant solution please.

The Microsoft cross platform C++ native activity solution uses ant in an arm64 configuration and installs fine, this error does not occur unless doing manually with adb install.

Comment: Check if your emulator image supports arm64-v8a emulation because natively Android emulators use x86-64 as your CPU is an x86 64 bit CPU. Some emulator images from Google support ARM emulation.

Comment: @Robert thanks, yes that was it.